# mysql dense_rank function is giving syntax error while it seems ok

Tags: mysql, group-by, window-functions, dense-rank

I am using below mysql command with dense_rank() function (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-dense_rank-function/) but its giving me error.. and i am not sure why as it looks ok to mee

```
select 
    product_category_id, 
    product_name,
    product_price,
    dense_rank() over (partition by product_category_id order by product_price desc) rank 
from products;
```

Error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by product_category_id order by product_price desc) rank from product' at line 1

My product table is as below

```
mysql> select * from products limit 3;
+------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| product_id | product_category_id | product_name                                  | product_description | product_price | product_image                                                                         |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1 |                   2 | Quest Q64 10 FT. x 10 FT. Slant Leg Instant U |                     |         59.98 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Quest+Q64+10+FT.+x+10+FT.+Slant+Leg+Instant+Up+Canopy |
|          2 |                   2 | Under Armour Men's Highlight MC Football Clea |                     |        129.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Under+Armour+Men%27s+Highlight+MC+Football+Cleat      |
|          3 |                   2 | Under Armour Men's Renegade D Mid Football Cl |                     |         89.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Under+Armour+Men%27s+Renegade+D+Mid+Football+Cleat    |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and some more details

```
mysql> describe products;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_category_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_name        | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_price       | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_image       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: What version of MySQL do you have? Window functions aren't available before version 8.

Comment: i just check its 

 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Yes, 5.1.73 is too old.

Comment: Thanks alot.. will check other methods